# Lock a previous form when opening a new one

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

There I have a `button_click` event and when it happens it opens a new Form. How do I lock the principal Form, so that it can't be looked at or changed until new Form is closed?

Here's my event handler:

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Form2 f = new Form2();
      f.Show();
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try showing the child form as a [modal window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx):

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Minor note - there can be some advantages to explicitly stating the owner, i.e. `f.ShowDialog(this)` - and a form shown with `ShowDialog(...)` should use `using` (it is not disposed via `ShowDialog` - only via `Show`).